# Disconnected reductive algebraic groups in Sage

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, root-systems, weights, sage

All simply connected split simple groups have been implement on Sage and it is possible to find their highest roots, fundamental weights, Dynkin diagrams or compute the tensor of two of their representations using the [Weyl Character Ring](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/lie/weyl_character_ring.html). Is there something similar for not simply connected groups as $\text{GL}_n$ or disconnected reductive algebraic group as $\text{SO}_n$?

Comment: Just to be clear, $\mathit{SO}_n$ is connected as an *algebraic* group (viꝫ. for the Zariski topology). The set of *real* points $\mathit{SO}_{⌊n/2⌋,⌈n/2⌉}(\mathbb{R})$ of the split real form (or indeed, any real form other than the compact one) has two connected components (for the real topology), but these two components are not algebraic. (Presumably you know this, but this is a common confusion, so it's worth spelling it out explicitly.)